# newbie - Drools filter from same fact

Tags: drools

I am newbie to drools. Need understanding how to cascade filtered data from one condition to next one as shown below.

```
rule "rulename"
when
  $var1 : MainObj(filter1)
  $var2 : SubObj() from $var1.getSubObj // need all SubObj without any filter here for then clause.
  $var3 : SubObj(conditions) from $var2 // Need a subset of SubObj for another then clause
then
  $var2.doSomething()
  $var3.doVar3Stuff()
end
```

How can I achieve that?

---

Continuation of my original post..

i have below rule computing statistics of a rule execution as below.

```
    rule "myrule"
       when
           $a:wrapper(isActive("ruleName") && dataTypeCode.equals("typeCodeinDB"))
           $total : Number() from accumulate($entity: MyObj(ObjAttribute=='testValue') from $a.getMyObj() , count( $entity ))
           $filter: MyObj(ObjAttribute=="testValue" && ObjAttribute2.equals("ValidValue")) from $a.getMyObj()
       then
      $filter.addToResults($filter.getRuleConstituents(),1,drools.getRule().getName(),null); // Add data for insertion in DB at later stage

   $filter.addPayloadExecution($a.dataTypeCode(),$a.getMyObj().toString(),$a.getMyObj().size()); //Total Count of MyObj

$filter.addRuleExecutions(drools.getRule().getName(), $total); // anotehr slice of data
           end
```

Here.. i am computing two stats.. Total count of MYObj(), apply some filter for data validation and compute count of valid list ($filter is valid data)

When I run that code I am getting error as below

```
Exception executing consequence for rule "MyRule" in moneta.rules: [Error: $filter.addRuleExecutions(drools.getRule().getName(), $total): null]
[Near : {... $filter.addToResults($filter.get ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1]
```

Need advice on resolving this.

Comment: I wrote my answer and then realized that maybe I misunderstood your question. Are you trying to cascade changes from one rule to another or something else? If something else, can you explain better because I don't know what you mean by "one condition to the next" in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell if you're trying to change the data in one rule and make it visible in another, or if you're trying to do a single complex condition in a single rule. So I'll outline how both work.

## Complex conditions

The pseudo-code in your rule indicates that you have a main object with a filter and a collection of sub-objects. You need to get a list of all sub-objects without a filter, and also to get a list of sub-objects that meet some sort of condition.

To collect these sublists, we have two available operations: `accumulate` and `collect`. Since you didn't give a real example, just some psuedo-code, I can't say for sure which is the correct one for you to use. The example I present below uses collect because it is appropriate for this use case. For more information about these operations, refer to the [Drools documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latestFinal/drools-docs/html_single/#drl-rules-WHEN-elements-ref_drl-rules). I've linked to the section on operators; scroll down to see the details for collect and accumulate.

So imagine I have an app that is modeling a school, and my KindergartenClass object has a List of Student objects. In this case, KindergartenClass is the main object, and Student is the sub-object. My Students have names, ages, and an Allergies object that indicates food allergies. Students without Allergies have no allergy object. This is going to be the filter for the example rule -- finding the students without allergies.

The rule would then look like:

```
rule "EXAMPLE"
when
  KindergartenClass( $students: students ) // $var1
  
  // Find all students with no allergies, $var2
  $var2: List() from collect( Student( allergies == null ) from $students )

  // Find all students who are older than 5, $var3
  $var3: List() from collect( Student( age > 5 ) from $students )
then
  ...
end
```

Obviously your right-hand-side would have to be adjusted because 'List' has no `doSomething()` and `doVar3Stuff()` methods. But without an *actual* example rule for what you're attempting I can't be more specific here.

You *could* get the individual students from the lists like this:

```
$studentWithoutAllergies: Student() from $var2
$studentOlderThan5: Student() from $var3
```

... but then your then-clause would trigger once for every single `$studentWithoutAllergies` *and* `$studentOlderThan5`. Most people don't want a cartesian product all elements in two lists and then having their consequences firing for each of those products.

Of course, you *also* talk about "cascading", though it's rather unclear what you mean. If you mean that you want $var3 to be a subset of what you found in $var2, then it's as simple as changing the `from` clause. So in the example I've been working with, if you actually want all students older than 5 who have no allergies, you can simply change the when clause to be:

```
// Find all students with no allergies, $var2
$var2: List() from collect( Student( allergies == null ) from $students )

// Find the subset of the non-allergy students who are older than 5, $var3
$var3: List() from collect( Student( age > 5 ) from $var2 )
```

## Changing the data that triggers the rule

There are two keywords available for changing the data available to the left hand side (when clause): `update` and `insert`. Which one you use depends on what you're trying to do, and come with very different considerations in terms of performance.

When you ask Drools to fire a set of rules, it first goes through all of the rules and determines if the rule fires, given the data you've inputted. Basically it just goes through, in order, all of the when clauses and decides if the rule is activated or not. Then, once it has the sub-set of rules, in order, it goes through, one by one, executing the right hand side.

If you call `update` in your right hand side (then clause), then this process repeats: all rules are evaluated again, from the top, including the rule you just fired. If you call `insert` in your then clause, then the new data is put into working memory, and Drools re-evaluates all of the remaining rules in its execution list. (So, for example, if Drools had decided that rules A, B, C, and D met their when criteria, and B inserts a new fact into working memory, then C and D would be re-evaluated to make sure that they were still valid.)

This is how you'd use them:

```
rule "Example rule with Update"
when
  $input: MyAwesomeInputObject(someValue == 0)
then
  $input.setSomeValue(99);
  $input.doSomeStuff();
  update($input);
end

rule "Example rule with Insert"
when
  Person(name == "Bob")
  not( Age() )
then
  Age age = new Age(18);
  insert(age); // there is now an Age object in working memory
end
```

I'm not 100% familiar with your use case, but I'm going to assume you want to fire all of the filtering rules a second time after your initial rule fires, with the updated data. So I'd do something like this:

```
rule "rulename"
when
  $var1 : MainObj(filter1)
  $var2 : SubObj() from $var1.getSubObj // need all SubObj without any filter here for then clause.
  $var3 : SubObj(conditions) from $var2 // Need a subset of SubObj for another then clause
then
  $var2.doSomething();
  $var3.doVar3Stuff();
  update($var1); // update the var1 in working memory
end
```

I have no idea what your when clause is trying to do, since it doesn't appear to match the comments and the syntax is completely wonky. So only the right hand side (then clause) has been adjusted. I have added `update($var1)` so it will refire the rules with the new instance of $var1 that should have your changes in it.

Of course, once you start re-firing all rules, you run the risk of having rules loop. If this does happen, you will see spikes of CPU and apparent thread deadlocks (this is useful to alert on.) Note that there is a `no-loop` property, but it won't help when you're calling update.